# Forgotten name of book, space knights

Tags: story-identification, books

I can’t remember too many plot details sorry but the book was about a travelling conquering alien race (that on the front cover were kind of dressed like knights in golden armour on horse like creatures) that destroys/enslaved other species across the galaxy. There was some interesting heraldry designs on the cover as well . I’m sorry I know this is vague! It may have been part of a series I’m sure there was at least a second book.

Comment: Sorry no that’s not it. It would say the novel was written in the 80’s-90’s. It’s definitely not Hyperion.

Comment: Julian May's Pliocene series had alien knight-like folks on flying horse-like critters.  Some of the covers match your descriptions.  Do a Google search for "julian may pliocene covers" and see if any of them jog your memory.

Comment: Longshot, but could it be Poul Anderson's 'The High Crusade' a lot of its cover images tally, but the story isn't quite as you recall it (being medieval earthmen fighting galactic empires).

Answer (score 2):

Thanks everyone for your suggestions, I was able to identify the novel as *Exile's Challenge* by Angus Wells.

The second book in the [Exiles Series](https://www.goodreads.com/series/151378-exiles) by Angus Wells, the first being [Exile's Children](https://www.goodreads.com/book/show/27889.Exile_s_Children). Published in 1996, the book is Angus' penultimate book.

> Escaping a life of servitude under the evil Autarchy, a warrior, his beautiful wife, and a gifted Dreamer are refugees from the war-ravaged prison colony of Salvation. It was the young Davyd's dreams, magically bound to those of a far-off Seer, that guided their perilous flight to the land of the Matawaye. But even now they might not be safe. For a man whose gifts are eclipsed by Davyd's is looking for the perfect vengeance. Meanwhile, a renegade band of the Matawaye, forced out by their peaceable leaders, is wreaking havoc on Salvation. And there's worse to come. For the real threat has yet to descend on Salvation--and when it does, its bloodlust and magic could well mean the end of them all.
>   <sub>[Exile's Challenge (Exiles, #2) - Goodreads synopsis](https://www.goodreads.com/book/show/2433540.Exile_s_Challenge)</sub>

[image: Cover of Exile's Children][image: Cover of Exile's Challenge]

Answer (score 0):

[image]

This is the cover I remember. There was heraldry symbols on the spine of the novel I think.

Comment: You should really be [editing](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/posts/175596/edit) this into the answer that you already have. If you've accidentally created 2 accounts you can get them merged by going here: [Merging accounts](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/help/merging-accounts)